# How to update vlookup when adding more rows

Tags: excel

I'm using VLOOKUP to calculate frequency in my raw data, the problem is that when I add a new information at the end of the information, the VLOOKUP doesnt work, and I can't add a new row in the middle of my data because I get this error :''you can't change part of the aray ''.

So how do I get VLOOKUP to work for the new added information too?

Comment: Use a table (Ctrl+T) for your lookup table.

Comment: What formula are you using? The error you're getting, IIRC, isn't technically a `VLOOKUP()` error, but an error with an array formula you're using? Or perhaps it's the VLOOKUP table you're referring to? Can you provide a little more info?

Comment: @BruceWayne This is a screenshot of my data https://pasteboard.co/Iqf2PTD.png I'm using groups to determine the frequency of dates in a range. And I use this customed range to create a graph. (RECHERCHEV = VLOOKUP in french)

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop till the last row where you have vlookup formulae. it should auto populate the formulae to newly added rows

Comment: @MelanieDeschene Try using calculate button at the left bottom once you drag and drop. Sometimes it happens when there are macros.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data, if I understand correctly, I *think* you can use this layout instead, which avoids the Array issue:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$H$7,3,TRUE)
```

But tweak your layout:
[image]

Comment: @MelanieDeschene - Can you describe how it's not working? Do you get an error? Is your data like I laid it out above?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it's giving me 366+ days for every cell when i only use 'B2'.

Comment: @MelanieDeschene - Check the formula, is it exactly as I have it? Do perhaps you did `=VLOOKUP($B$2,...)` or `B$2`?  A final check is to fill in `G7` with a huge number, e.g. `10000000`